# Copy a local folder to remote server

Tags: cmd, xcopy, robocopy

I want to copy a folder to a remote machine.

I tried to use *xcopy* and *robocopy*; but there is no way to add username and Password in copy command.

How can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know on what type of remote machine you are, assuming its linux/unix:

1. You would need ssh daemon running on the remote machine.
2. Then from the local machine you can use following, depending on the
   OS:

   **Windows**: Use winscp.exe, its pretty easy you google it you will have a fare idea

   **Linux/UNix**: `scp -r <path to the file/folder>  username@<ip or hostname of remote machine>:<absolute path where you want to store the copied file/folder>`

`-r` for copying a folder

If remote machine is windows you will have to use a exe which starts ssh daemon.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use `NET SHARE` from one machine to make a directory available. Then, use `NET USE` on the other machine to map a drive letter to the shared directory.